# Spring Boot Version Upgrade Performance Issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We are working on a project with spring-boot-starter version **1.5.10.RELEASE** and spring-cloud-services version 1.5.10.RELEASE and spring cloud version **Camden.SR7**.

Few weeks back we upgraded the spring-boot-starter version to **2.1.2.RELEASE** and spring-cloud-services version to 2.1.2.RELEASE and spring cloud version to **Greenwhich.RELEASE**.

After this we are getting performance issues. Previously we used to get the response back in 80-100ms but now we are getting the response in 500-600ms.

Please let us know if there is anything that can be done to improve the performance.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Were you able to pinpoint exactly where you are seeing the slowness? If you have an APM tool, you can drill down the transactions.

Comment: Why don’t you update to the latest versions?

Comment: @Rahul sorry for the late reply. we are seeing the slowness in the calling microservice. We can drill down the transactions using APM tool at our end. But we need to track even at the calling service.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero Even we want to use the latest versions. But when we use the latest versions we are facing issues in the performance.

Comment: Can you add a request tracing tool/framework?

Comment: @user3318121 does that happen with the actual latest? I mean, the ones in the post are not it

Comment: @MarcosBarbero I had tried with Spring boot version 2.2.1 but that has also not helped. We have added sleuth to trace.

Comment: What does sleuth say? :)